# Opening CSV files encoded using utf-8-sig in python 3.3 using numpy's genfromtxt()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to open a CSV file encoded using `utf-8-sig` using python 3.3 and numpy's `genfromtxt()` function. This file is generated by another piece of software which I do not have control over. If I open the file by directly specifying the file path, the very first value is `nan`. I believe this happens because `genfromtxt()` does not decode the text file correctly. After a bit of trial and error I was able to clobber together this code that works quite well.

```
import numpy as np
import io

fid = open('filename.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
data = np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(fid.read().encode('ascii')), delimiter=',')
```

Does anyone know of a more elegant way of doing this instead of using this decode-encode-wrapper method?

Comment: I think you mean `encoding='utf-8-sig'` in the call to `open`.

Comment: have you tried `np.fromfile`?

Comment: @ali_m I tried it and it didn't work. I was able to only read a single value in (-1)

Comment: does genfromtxt expect a bytes stream object? You could just do open('filename.csv', 'rb'). then np.genfromtxt(fid, delimiter=','). Sounds like numpy should accept a unicode stream if it's a method called "genfromtxt".